# Typescript - Better way to enforce an object's key type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to define a type (interface) of an object's key.

Couldn't find how to do it on StackOverflow or anywhere else.

I have crafted this method, it works but I find it clumsy. Is there any "official" syntax for it?

```
interface Report {
    action: string;
    exists?: boolean;
    warnings? : string[];
    errors? : string[];
}

let patent: Patent = {
        numbers: { … },
        dates : { … },
        report: ( ():Report => ({ // This works, it enforces the key's type but looks ugly
            action : "create",
            exists : false,
            otherKey : "otherValue" // Typescript detects this wrong key, that's good
        }))()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking: you would define the type of the `report` property in the definition of `Patent`. So:

```
interface Report {
    action: string;
    exists?: boolean;
    warnings? : string[];
    errors? : string[];
}

class Patent {
  numbers: any;
  dates: any;
  report: Report;
}

let patent: Patent = {
        numbers: { },
        dates : { },
        report: {
            action : "create",
            exists : false,
            otherKey : "otherValue" // Typescript detects this wrong key, that's good
        }
}
```

gives you an error for `otherKey` just as you might have expected. The actual error is:

```
error TS2322: Type '{ numbers: {}; dates: {}; report: { action: string; exists: false; otherKey: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Patent'.
  Types of property 'report' are incompatible.
    Type '{ action: string; exists: false; otherKey: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Report'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'otherKey' does not exist in type 'Report'.
```

However it is worth noting that you'll only get that error for a literal value, as an object that simply implements an interface may have as many additional attributes as it wants, so the extra attributes wouldn't be a problem in that case.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.